# owlCarousel - slider 100% width

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Уже голову сломал всю, вроде бы кажется элементарно, но я что-то не могу понять как оно правильно будет.

**Вот HTML:**

```
<!-- Start Slider One-->
<div class="g__slider">
    <div class="g__slide">
        <div class="g__slide-bg" style="background-image: url(img/g__slidebg.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="g__slide-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="g__slide-right">
                                        <img src="img/g__logoslide.png" alt="">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> Обшырный спектр услуг по очистке канализаций</li>
                                            <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> Профессиональные специалисты в своей сфере</li>
                                            <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> Современная профессиональная техника</li>
                                            <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> Самые выгодные цены по Одессе и Украине</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="g__slide-left">
                                        <img src="img/g__slider-rothen.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="g__slide">
            <div class="g__slide-bg" style="background-image: url(img/g__slidebg.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="g__slide-content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="g__slide-right">
                                            <img src="img/g__logoslide.png" alt="">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 2 Обшырный спектр услуг по очистке канализаций</li>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 2 Профессиональные специалисты в своей сфере</li>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 2 Современная профессиональная техника</li>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 2 Самые выгодные цены по Одессе и Украине</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="g__slide-left">
                                            <img src="img/g__slider-rothen.png" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="g__slide">
            <div class="g__slide-bg" style="background-image: url(img/g__slidebg.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="g__slide-content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="g__slide-right">
                                            <img src="img/g__logoslide.png" alt="">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 3 Обшырный спектр услуг по очистке канализаций</li>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 3 Профессиональные специалисты в своей сфере</li>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 3 Современная профессиональная техника</li>
                                                <li><img src="img/g__circle-slider-yellow.png" alt="" class="g__cirle-yellow"> 3 Самые выгодные цены по Одессе и Украине</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="g__slide-left">
                                            <img src="img/g__slider-rothen.png" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- End Slider One-->
```

**Вот CSS код:**

```
.g__slider
.g__slide
    position: relative
    color: #fff
    width: 100%
    &-wrap
        float: left
    &-bg
        position: absolute
        background-size: cover
        top: 0
        left: 0
        right: 0
        bottom: 0
        min-height: 620px
        &::before
            content: ''
            background-color: #292929
            top: 0
            left: 0
            width: 100%
            height: 100%
            position: absolute
            opacity: 0.85
    &-content
        z-index: 1
        position: relative
    &-right
        padding-top: 225px
    &-left
        padding-top: 96px
        margin-left: -45px
ul, li
    list-style-type: none
    padding: 0
li
    font-size: 18px
    font-weight: 700
```

**Вот настройки JS самой owlCarousel:**

```
var owl = $(".g__slider");
```

owl.owlCarousel({
    items : 1,
    nav : true,
    navText : "",
    loop : true,
    autoplay : true,
    autoplayHoverPause : true,
    fluidSpeed : 3000,
    autoplaySpeed : 3000,
    navSpeed : 3000,
    dotsSpeed : 3000,
    dragEndSpeed : 3000,
    itemClass: "g__slide-wrap"
});

$(".next").click(function(){
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
}),
$(".prev").click(function(){
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});

**В итоге я получаю вот что:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такой велосипед ради слайдера

Comment: Можете дать ссылку? Хочу это увидеть.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, у вас как раз тот слон, которого по кусочкам надо. Вот первый кусочек:

По умолчанию бутстрап использует 12-колоночный макет. Поэтому класс `col-md-12` растягивает блок на всю ширину родителя. А класс `col-md-offset-1` выталкивает его на одну колонку вправо. Из-за этого на экранах от 992px правый край блока оказывается за экраном.

[image: скриншот горизонтальной прокрутки на экране шириной 993px]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x400/c69/f9c/?text=Problem%20at%20992px" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```